# How should I build my object structure to balance collection classes and objects

Tags: objective-c, oop, object, collections

Not too sure how to explain this one, but here goes...

I'm building an object structure for my data (in Objective-C) to have the following:

- A `Companies` collection class

  - which contains many `Company` objects

    - each one of these has a `Users` collection class

      - which contains many `User` objects

The aim is to have data on the objects (i.e. `companyID`, `companyName`), and methods on the collection classes (`addCompany:`, `deleteCompany:`).

What I really want to do is to structure the classes so that I can make the following call:

```
[[companies getCompanyWithID:1] addUserWithName:@"Duncan"];
```

But to do that, I would need to put the method `addUserWithName:` on the companies collection class.

To me that doesn't make sense - the methods to add/amend/delete/get users should be on the `Users` collection class, not on the `Companies` collection class.

If I put those function on their relevant collection classes, I then have to write the same statement like this:

```
[[companies getCompanyWithID:1].users addUserWithName:@"Duncan"];
```

But then it doesn't read as nicely - because it has a nasty `.users` lurking in the middle.

Am I being really dumb and missing something obvious (I never went to techie school, so it's likely I missed something fundamental which you guys all know about).

Any help, much appreciated guys.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your concern, but I don't think this is an issue. Your user management methods would be on `Company`, not `Companies`, and that's generally an acceptable pattern.

Let's go with the assumption that you have four classes: `Companies`/`Company` and `Users`/`User`. Now we can define a method:

```
@interface Companies
- (Company *)companyWithID:(NSUInteger)id;
@end
```

This says that the `Companies` class can get you back a `Company` by its ID. (Side note: in Objective-C, we rarely use the `get...` prefix for accessor methods - just start the method with the thing that you want, in this case `company...`.)

The traditional thing to do from here would be to have your `Company` class expose a good chunk of public API for managing users. You might do something like:

```
@interface Company
- (void)addUserWithName:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

In turn, the `Company` class will be responsible for knowing about the inner workings of the `Users` collection, including modifying it as necessary. With that in mind, you could write:

```
@implementation Company
- (void)addUserWithName:(NSString *)name {
    [self.users addObject:name]; // self.users is of type `Users *`
}
@end
```

This way, you avoid exposing the `.users` to external clients of the `Company` class - you just pass the `add...` message forward.

You could even take this strategy further and say that the `Users` collection class is an implementation detail and *never* needs to be exposed to clients of the `Company` class. Instead, you could provide accessors to your `Users` collection in terms of a more standard system collection object:

```
@interface Company
- (NSSet *)users;
- (void)addUserWithName:(NSString *)name;
- (void)removeUserWithName:(NSString *)name;
// and so on...
@end
```

The absolute extreme of this thought process would lead you to get rid of your `Users` class altogether and just use system classes to manage the collection of users directly on your `Company` class. On one hand, this would let Xcode infer and suggest (through autocompletion) certain methods that fit this pattern well - take a look at the [KVC compliance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html) section of the Key-Value Coding Programming Guide for such methods. On the other hand, you may have more complexity that doesn't show up in your question, so the `Users` class may be necessary for your use case.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Awesome answer.  I understand everything you've said and it all sounds great, except that I don't want my Company object being responsible for my Users.  I know you're suggesting that this is the standard practise, but what i really want is to keep all the USER methods away from the COMPANY methods, and only link the two in one place.  I'm going to think some more about this, but I'll mark you are the correct answer if nobody else trumps you with another suggestion.